# why my job are not performed during test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

here a small description of my code (simplified)

app/jobs/

```
class GenerateInvoiceJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform()
    Invoice.create
  end
end
```

app/models/

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def buy
    GenerateInvoiceJob.perform_later
  end
end
```

spec/jobs

```
RSpec.describe AnotherJob, type: :job do

  context "with filter" do
    ...
  end
end
```

spec/models

```
RSpec.describe Product, type: :model do


    describe '#buy' do
      it "should generate invoice" do
        Product.create().buy

        expect(Invoice.all.size).to eq 1
      end
    end
end
```

with rails 4.2.11

when I run

> rspec spec/models/product_spec.rb

then the test is ok (the job is performed)

when I run

> rspec spec -e 'should generate invoice'

then the test fail cause the job is not performed

if I delete all test jobs from spec/jobs and then run

> rspec spec -e 'should generate invoice'

then the test is ok (the job is performed)

I can't understand why having some tests for jobs prevents other jobs to perform ? Is there a solution for this?

with rails 5 and rails 6

whatever I do, the test always failed as the job is never performed ?

Aren't jobs performed anymore during tests since rails 5 ?

thanks for help

***update 1 after first answer :***

thanks a lot for your answer
just to be sure I do correctly :

I added in environment/test.rb
  config.active_job.queue_adapter = :test

and in my spec/models/product_spec.rb

```rb
  RSpec.describe Product, type: :model do
    describe '#buy' do
      it "should generate invoice" do
        ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true
        Product.create().buy

        expect(Invoice.all.size).to eq 1
      end
    end
  end
```

not sure I put

```
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true
```

at the good place ?!

Answer (score 7):

You need to set:

```rb
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true
```

However, using [`have_enqueued_job`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-9/docs/matchers/have-enqueued-job-matcher) is a more common approach.

EDIT: There's even an easier way that slipped my mind:

```rb
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :inline
```

Comment: I edited my question after your answer, could you please have a look ?

Comment: Does the spec pass @user2016483?

Comment: Yea, ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter.perform_enqueued_jobs = true works like a magic. Where is the best place to put it to enable for all tests?

Comment: @BenjaminHarel It does, but I wouldn't recommend this to everyone, as it breaks test boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

you need to wrap your code in `perform_enqueued_jobs`

```
it 'test request' do
  perform_enqueued_jobs do
    expect(request).to be_success
  end
end
```